# Special characters for removing multi spaces in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am removing multi spaces from a text. I cant understand what does the comma do after the "2". On https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions it says that just the "{2}" should locate all the doubles.

```
return newsong.replace(/\s{2}/g, ' ')

return newsong.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ')
```

Very confused....

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Answer (score 2):

The comma matches 2 **or more** spaces, allowing you to remove spaces from strings like:

```
part1     part2
```

as well. If you use the first regex on this one (no comma), it'll see this:

```
part1<SPACE><SPACE><SPACE><SPACE><SPACE>part2
```

The first two spaces are removed, then the next two, leaving you with

```
part1<SPACE>part2
```

This last space isn't matched by `\s{2}` and will remain. If you use the comma, it'll just remove them all in one go because that matches 2 or more spaces.

Also, if you put another number after the comma, you can set a maximum number of spaces to match.

Comment: Notice that it doesn't *remove* spaces, it *replaces* them with a single space. Your example will end up with 3 spaces instead of 1, not with 1 instead of 0.

Comment: I want also to remove words. Why does this not work? songText.replace(/WUB{1,}/g, " ");

Answer (score 2):

The range meta sequence consist of two parts, minimum matches and maximum matches.

```
{n, m}
```

Where `n` is minimum and `m` is maximum.

When only one is specified it's considered as both minimum and maximum, eg: `x{2}` will match two x'es

When manimum is omitted it will match 0 .. maximum times, eg: `x{,2}` will match zero, one or two x'es

When maximum is omitted it will match minimum or more times, eg: `x{2,}` will match two or more x'es

Comment: Thank you for the great answer!

Comment: I want also to remove words. Why does this not work? songText.replace(/WUB{1,}/g, " ");

Comment: @AlexeyTseitlin A range selector will only work the character or group before it. Use `/(?:WUB){1,}/g` or in your case since it's 1 or more: `/(?:WUB)+/g`